# Class with hierachy of functions

Tags: c#, .net, class

I want to make a class library with a hierachy of functions and properties.
In my imagined pesudo code it could be like this:

```
public class SomethingHandler{
  private string _someGlobalSalt;
  public SomethingHandler(string salt){
    _someGlobalSalt= salt;
  }

  public class NestOfFunctions{
    public string HandleStuff(string input){
        return input + "With" + _someGlobalSalt;
    }
  }
}
```

And I would consume it like this:

```
var newHandlerObject = new SomethingHandler("SaltAndPepperOn");
var result = newHandlerObject.NestOfFunctions.HandleStuff("Salad");
```

Now if this were the way to do it `result` would contain `"SaladWithSaltAndPepperOn"`.

But I realize that this is NOT the way to do this, since the child classes should be ignorant of the parent class, but how then can I make a group of nested classes with a common property?

Comment: Could you put this more into the context of what your requirements are? It is difficult to understand what you are trying to achieve here.

Comment: Sure. I'll try to clarify.

Comment: What is setting?

Comment: Sorry Marco..  typo..  Corrected in OP

Comment: Why should that method be nested inside another class?

Comment: `newHandlerObject.NestOfFunctions` doesn't make sense. Nested types aren't something you can reference with instances of parent types. You better explain in words what you want to achieve, not how to fix your broken (attempted) solution, see [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/299295).

Comment: maybe you want to achieve something like Builder Design Pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it this way:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var newHandlerObject = new SomethingHandler.NestOfFunctions("SaltAndPepperOn");
        var result = newHandlerObject.HandleStuff("Salad");
        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
}

public class SomethingHandler
{
    public class NestOfFunctions
    {
        private string _someGlobalSalt;

        public NestOfFunctions(string salt)
        {
            _someGlobalSalt = salt;
        }
        public string HandleStuff(string input)
        {
            return input + "With" + _someGlobalSalt;
        }
    }
}
```

The use is:

```
        var newHandlerObject = new SomethingHandler.NestOfFunctions("SaltAndPepperOn");
        var result = newHandlerObject.HandleStuff("Salad");
```

OR

```
        var result = new SomethingHandler.NestOfFunctions("SaltAndPepperOn").HandleStuff("Salad");
```